# Edit removes "Marked as Duplicate" box

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I recently visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758912/jquery-not-executing-on-wamp) question and was following the comment stream. While I was on it I tried to cast a close vote. I was prompted by the box that said something to the effect of "This question has already been closed.". I refreshed my browser window by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. The question reloaded and I saw the box stating:

> **marked as duplicate by [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan), [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) 8 mins ago**
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

About 30 secs or so after this question was posted, *@harryg*'s edit was approved and the edit banner appeared above the question. I clicked to see the latest edit and the close box disappeared.

The top:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>
> [Jquery is not working in localhost wamp [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757960/jquery-is-not-working-in-localhost-wamp) *1 answer*

box was still visible on the question but the "marked as duplicate" box (above) disappeared. When I refreshed the page again with <kbd>F5</kbd> it reappeared.

I haven't been able to recreate this scenario again. Was this a weird glitch or is it a reproducable bug? It seemed like the edit made the box disappear but it could have been a coincidence.

Comment: You're not the only one to experience this; it's happened to me several times. I didn't pay attention to what exactly vanished, though. All I know is that at least one of the grey boxes vanished...